# Le fait d'être constructif

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions, demande-de-mot, substantivation

On peut dire des remarques de quelqu’un qu’elles sont constructives quand elles apportent un intérêt à la discussion, et qu’elles permettent d’avancer. Quel est le mot pour dire que les remarques, les critiques d’une personne sont constructives ?

J’ai pensé à :

> Je suis bien entendu à l’écoute de toute remarque sur ces arguments, temps bien sur qu’elle respecte les principes élémentaires de **constructivité**.

Mais cela ne me semble pas vraiment français...

Comment: Je suis bien entendu à l’écoute de toute remarque sur ces arguments, tant qu’elle respecte les principes élémentaires de constructivité.

Comment: Donc constructivité est valable comme mot ? Il ne me semble pas pourtant...

Comment: voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/constructivit%C3%A9

Comment: Non, constructivité(e) n'existe pas, c'était pour pour vous faire remarque qu'une qualit**é** n' pas de *e* à la fin :)

Comment: Ah, oui, merci beaucoup! Je ne l'avais pas remarqué.

Comment: @cccg03 Il n'est ni à l'Académie française, (http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm) ni dans le petit Robert de 1996. Il faut donc éviter de l'employer, sauf comme terme technique (il est d'ailleurs entre guillemets dans la référence citée) ou lié à une spécialité   qui possède son jargon bien défini.

Comment: @cl-r mais si, le voici dans le TLFi -http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1754774085; et je n'ai jamais dit de l'employer, mais simplement de se référer au lien pour voir que le most _existe_ mais se dit justement plutôt rarement et dans un contexte vachement différent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Je suis bien entendu à l’écoute de toute remarque sur ces arguments, tant qu’elle reste constructive.

Comment: C’est vrai que, donné comme ça, ça évite le problème :)

Comment: @WayToDoor ... et c'est surtout plus facile à prononcer :) . C'est la formule usuelle que vous pourrez entendre. Elle est aussi puissante (elle a autant de force comminatoire) à l'oral (puisque l'orateur 'écoute' et attend une réponse) que la phrase proposée (en acceptant le néologisme en question) sans paraître pédant.

Comment: C'est exactement ce que je recherchais ! Merci beaucoup !

Comment: Attention à l'orale on ne saura pas si tu attends une ou plusieurs remarques.

Comment: @Knu -- C’est vrai, mais cette formulation sous-entend *toute sorte de remarques* ou *des remarques de toute sorte*, je m’attends donc à avoir au moins une remarque qui peut en déclencher d’autres. Sinon la question aurait « Y a-t-il une remarque à faire ? »